# why is my internationalization not working (Spring Boot Application)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is how I added internationalization to my Spring application.

First, I added to the class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    // ...
}
```

method (here I set default language - Polish):

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pl"));
    return slr;
}
```

Next, in the class that implements the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface, I added the following two methods:

```
@Component
public class WebMvcConfigurerImpl implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // ...

    // Configuring a component that supports changing language settings
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }


    // Registering a component that supports changing the language
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

After adding the code above, I created two files `labels.properties` and `labels_en.properties` in the `resources` folder.
In these files, I will write the `key=value` format to the text that will be shown on the pages (I use Thymeleaf).

Next, we need to register these files in the application, for this, in the `application.properties` file, I added the name labels to `spring.messages.basename`, this is how it looks:

```
spring.messages.basename=errors-messages,labels
```

Now, when the page in the request receives ...?lang=en (the `lang` parameter with the value `en`), the labels on the page should have changed, but it doesn't.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to slightly modify your code. Instead of using `some_url?lang=en` use `some_url?lang=en_GB`.

For instance you can have a link that will trigger a language change to english

```
 <a  id="link_en_GB" href="/some_url?lang=en_GB" >English</a>
```

EDIT:
I've just tried a language change using `some_url?lang=en` and that also works so I guess the problem isn't the url itself but something else. Make sure that you have a controller method matching /some_url and that the user has the right privilages to access it.

Comment: What does `_GB` mean? It did not help

Comment: @mzlvv4k, GB for Great Britain (you can also have en_US etc.). This code actually works in my application.  Can your application access labels.properties?

Comment: Yes, my application has access to `labels.properties`. But the language change still doesn't work.

Comment: @mzlvv4k, the only difference that I can see in your code from mine is that in my code the localeResolver method is placed in the class implementing the WebMvcConfigurer interface. Not sure if it's going to make any difference to move it there though.

Comment: to debug this, hit F12 (developer tools) in your browser and switch to the Network tab. You should see something like  `some_url?lang=en_GB` with the corresponding http status (I'm getting 200 here, but you will probably get 4xx or 3xx )¨.